# XAMPP Apache error AH01599: Cannot get media type from 'x-httpd-php53'

Tags: apache-http-server, php, xampp, wordpress, htaccess

I'm trying to setup Xampp on a Mac (OSX 10.10.2), its setup and normal PHP runs, however when I try and run a Wordpress site the PHP code doesn't execute, it just prints out in the browser and I keep getting this error in my Apache error logs:

> [Wed Apr 01 19:01:27.833570 2015] [mime:warn] [pid 43890] AH01599:
>   Cannot get media type from 'x-httpd-php53'

I've tried adding these lines suggested by others to both my .htaccess files and both httpd.conf files:

```
AddType x-httpd-php53 .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

This hasn't changed anything though, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a module. Try running `a2enmod php5` as root, restarting Apache, and then try again.

I had the same problem with an `AddHandler cgi-script .pl`, in which cas an `a2enmod cgi` helped.